# Yahoo weather api is it only for United State's cities!??

Tags: python, yahoo-api, weather-api

I'm able to find weather report of cities of US and I want to extend it for the cities in India. It will be still better if I could do it for all the cities in the world. This is the code i was using.

```
import pywapi
import string

yahoo_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo('RSXX0199', 'metric')

print "Yahoo says: It is " + string.lower(yahoo_result['condition']['text']) + " and " + yahoo_result['condition']['temp'] + "C now in New York.\n\n"`
```

I'm not able to find a code for Indian states, cities codes, for which i can replace with `RSXX0199`. By the way, I'm using Python API for weather, which internally uses Yahoo's weather API.

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the RSS feed of an individual location, the identifier you are looking for is in it's address.

For instance, [Karimnagar, India](http://weather.yahoo.com/india/andhra-pradesh/karimnagar-2295185/)'s RSS feed is "weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=**INXX0358**&u=f" and can be retrieved by clicking the RSS button in the top right.

Comment: Thanks its working :) but still i'm not able to find  out how to get values of P? i'm not able to figure it out how to get values for p.. Please share me some link that has codes for all the cities..

Comment: I could find the code for cities only by clicking that rss link, its not robust to check the code for each city and update, can you please suggest better solution for finding the value of p, by giving just location name!?

Comment: So, you want a way to give the city and get the code, through the python API?

Comment: If you haven't already written all your processing code, you could simply use `pywapi.get_weather_from_google` which can take city and country. I don't see a way to use the API to get the code based on city/country for yahoo.

Comment: i actually tried google's weather api too, it is also taking just US zip code which is oly 5 digits. Its not taking India's zip code :(

Comment: it can also take city,country

Comment: No its giving index out of bound error for more den 5 digit number:(

Answer (score 2):

You can use Yahoo Weather API with any city of the world listed in http://weather.yahoo.com/

**How to know the identifier of the city?**

1. Search the city you are looking for (in my case: http://weather.yahoo.com/venezuela/anzoategui/lecheria-420107/)
2. View Source code of that page (In Google Chrome: right clic --> View Page Source. Sorry, I like to be specific).
3. In the code, search for: "weather.com/weather/extended"
4. The identifier of the city is the value next to that link, in my case: VEXX0025

Hope this tip can help anybody!

Answer (score 0):

No,I use their api to build an app for weather change alert in China.

Yahoo weather api use use yahoo wdid(a code stands for a city) to request for the weather condition.

So first you should get the wdid of the city.